# C- to check if a char in a string belongs in an array

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops, char

Basically what I'm trying to do is that when a user inputs a string, my code will check the characters one by one and see if they belong to an array or not.

```
For instance i have an array:
char example[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
```

And let's say the user inputs a string "example string"
   Now i want to check every single character individually in the string 
   if they exist in the given array. So the first letter "e" clearly is in the array
   and whereas the letter "x" doesn't exist in the given array. So far I'm trying to
   use a loop and the memchr, but it just won't work for some reason, here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char array[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
    char input[40]; /*Reserved for the string*/
    int lengthofstring,i;
    scanf("%[^\n]s",input); /*This enables spaces in the input, and let's say 
    the string in this case is "example"*/
    lengthofstring=strlen(input);
    for (i=0;i<lengthofstring;i++){
        if (memchr(array,input[i],sizeof(array)){
            /* Now in this example input[i]="e", when i=0 and sizeof(array)=5*/
            printf("The letter %c does exist\n",input[i]);
        }
        else {
            printf("The letter %c does NOT exist\n",input[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm really having a hard time to figure out what is wrong with this code, it always ends up in the does NOT exist category for some reason. Any advice or help is really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: One problem is that you are missing a closing parenthesis, when that is fixed it *appears* to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code seems to be working for me. I did edit the code in the question, I may have unintentionally removed the problem. Please feel free to re-edit and post the original code, I can't seem to rollback my edit.

Working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char array[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
    char input[40]; /*Reserved for the string*/
    int lengthofstring,i;
    scanf("%[^\n]s",input); /*This enables spaces in the input, and let's say 
    the string in this case is "example"*/
    lengthofstring=strlen(input);
    for (i=0;i<lengthofstring;i++){
        if (memchr(array,input[i],sizeof(array))) {
            /* Now in this example input[i]="e", when i=0 and sizeof(array)=5*/
            printf("The letter %c does exist\n",input[i]);
        }
        else {
            printf("The letter %c does NOT exist\n",input[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

My additions, 2 closing `}` and a closing `)` on the `if` statement

Original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
char array[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
char input[40]; /*Reserved for the string*/
int lengthofstring,i;
scanf("%[^\n]s",input); /*This enables spaces in the input, and let's say 
the string in this case is "example"*/
lengthofstring=strlen(input);
for (i=0;i<lengthofstring;i++){
if (memchr(array,input[i],sizeof(array)){
/* Now in this example input[i]="e", when i=0 and sizeof(array)=5*/
printf("The letter %c does exist\n",input[i]);}
else {
printf("The letter %c does NOT exist\n",input[i]);}
```

Comment: Got it working now thanks. I just realised I had spacings between the letters in the array, once I removed them the code started to run properly. Annoying small mistakes seem to cause the biggest problems.